# Exporting DLL description - reference with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll

I colleague of mine asked me to see a dll that he needs to use. So I used the Object Browser on Visual Studio 2012. Now he asked me if I can export like a text version of the dll reference (methods signatures and properties).

Is there a way to do it?

I can already see something like

```
short get_Param(short sNumParam)
    Member of LMLib.ISWKey
```

on the windows dedicated to the description. I just need to put every method in a single file.

Comment: It should be fairly easy to write code that prints this using Reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a trick and have the IDE generate the definitions for you.  Write a sliver of code in the text editor, similar to:

```
 var obj = new LMLib.ISWKey();
```

Right-click ISWKey in the text editor and select "Go To Definition".  You'll get a new text file with the definitions, auto-generated from the metadata.

If it is a COM interface, sure sounds like it with a name like that, then you can run Oleview.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Use File + View Typelib, select the type library of the COM server and you'll get the auto-generated IDL for the server.  Prefer this approach if it is in fact a COM server, you'll get more info, including the [helpstring] attributes.

And of course, don't hesitate to ask the owner of the DLL for documentation.  You paid good money for the license to use the DLL.

Comment: I'm not kidding, I think the owner is dead. I'll try tomorrow with the trick.